# In css: when button is pressed colour and size of div must be change

Tags: html, css

whenever we clicked on the play button in figure(generated by given code),
colour of all the division must change continuously and and size of all divisions must be double than the original.
I want to solve this question using **CSS only**, no JavaScript.
Please some one help me to solve it using CSS.

Code:-

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Question 3</title>
</head>
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
  }
  #second {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px 100px;
    background: lightblue;
  }
  #first {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px 100px;
    background: red;
  }
  #fourth {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px 100px;
    background: yellow;
  }
  #third {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100px 100px;
    background: orange;
  }
  figure {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: -125px;
    left: 75px;
  }
  figure button[name="play_button"] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  figure button[name="play_button"]:focus {
    border: 0px;
  }
  figure button[name="play_button"]::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    top: 1px;
    left: 3px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent lightblue;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
    <div id="fourth"></div>
  </div>
  <figure>
    <button name="play_button"></button>
  </figure>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way just using css, but good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Semantically it doesn't make sense but by using the pseudo selectors `input:checked ~ div` you can select the siblings following the input when it's checked and apply CSS without any triggering Javascript.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: .3s all ease;
          transition: .3s all ease;
}

div:nth-of-type(even) {
  position: relative;
}

div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  top: 75px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: .3s all ease;
          transition: .3s all ease;
}

input::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 18px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked {
  left: 175px;
  top: 175px;
}

input:checked ~ div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

input:checked ~ div {
  -webkit-animation-name: color1;
          animation-name: color1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
          animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-duration: 2s;
}

input:checked ~ div:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-name: color1;
          animation-name: color1;
}

input:checked ~ div:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-name: color2;
          animation-name: color2;
}

input:checked ~ div:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-name: color3;
          animation-name: color3;
}

input:checked ~ div:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-name: color4;
          animation-name: color4;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color1 {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@keyframes color1 {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes color2 {
  0% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
@keyframes color2 {
  0% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes color3 {
  0% {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
@keyframes color3 {
  0% {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes color4 {
  0% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
@keyframes color4 {
  0% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```